# How to hide submit button if table shows error

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and have a question on how to hide the submit button if any of the table  shows 'Error'

This is what I've written thus far but not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('table').highlight("Error");

                if ($('table').contains('Error')) {
                    $("#ProcessReshop").hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: you can try to disable the button instead of hiding it

Comment: do you check your codes for errors in firebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, [Demo of JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3WcU/)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      //  alert($('table').text());
        if($('table').text().indexOf("Error") != -1)
        {
            alert("error");
             $("#ProcessReshop").hide();
        }
    });​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('table td').each(function(){
  if ($(this) + ':contains("Error")'){
    $("#ProcessReshop").hide();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The contains function you are using is looking for DOM elements. Try this instead:

```
    if(​$("table:contains('Error')")==$("table")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​){
        $("#ProcessReshop").hide();
    }​
```